# Date and Time filter working fine with find() operation but issues with $match with aggregate in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, datefilter

I am building dynamic query as follow:

```
           if(DateX && DateY){
                query.createdAt = {
                    $gte: new Date(DateX).toISOString(),
                    $lt : new Date(DateY).toISOString() 
                }

            }else if(DateX){
                query.createdAt = {
                    $gte: new Date(DateX).toISOString() 
                }

            }else if(DateY){
                query.createdAt = {
                    $lt: new Date(DateY).toISOString() 
                }
            }
```

Here my dates DateX and DateY are dates in tz format.

Above query working fine with find() as below and returns desired results:

```
Model.find(query).lean().exec();
```

But the same query is not working with `aggregate.match(query)` as follow:

```
Model.aggregate()
            .match(query)
            .exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to convert `new Date(DateX)` and `new Date(DateY)` to ISO format date-time string which was not working here. As `new Date()` constructor itself  returns the `ISODate` with the specified date.

I just removed the `.toISOString()` from `new Date().toISOString()` and it started working fine.

As per the mongodb official doc [says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/):

- new Date("") returns the ISODate with the specified date.
- new Date("") specifies the datetime in the
  client’s local timezone and returns the ISODate with the specified
  datetime in UTC.
- new Date("") specifies the    datetime in UTC
  and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime    in UTC.
- new Date() specifies the datetime as milliseconds    since
  the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), and returns the resulting ISODate
  instance.